# How to delete a specific item ​in django jsonfield

Tags: json, django, django-models

here is my model:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, verbose_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    log = models.JSONField(verbose_name='log', default=list, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

the data(log.log) like this:

```
[
  {"date": "2021-1-1", "volume": 123},
  {"date": "2021-2-1", "volume": 456}, // if post date is 2021-2-1, i want delete this
  {"date": "2021-3-1", "volume": 789}
]
```

this this delete view:

```
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        date = request.data.get('date', None)
        if not date:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        user = request.user
        log = Log.objects.filter(user=user).first()
        if not log:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        # delete data based on date
        # data = json.dumps(log.log)
        ...
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I'm not good at json, tried a few ways but failed.

Very grateful for any answer

Comment: What is the format of `date`? Is this the same as the `"date"`s in the JSON blob?

Comment: date is string, but it doesn't matter, it's just a simple example, it could be other strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    date = request.data.get('date', None)
    if not date:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = request.user
    log = Log.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    if not log:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    log.log = [
        item for item in log.log
        if item['date'] != date
    ]
    log.save()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However if the data is structured, as seems to be the case in your JSON data, it is better in a relational database to work with an extra model, so:

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    log = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()
```

in fact, in that case `log` makes no sense, and you can refer to the `UserProfile` directly. This will make the update to the database more efficiently, and furthermore the database can validate data, for example by preventing that you store something that is not a date in the `date` field.

If one uses a JSON blob, we fully deserialize the blob, remove the entry, and then serialize the result again. This thus scales linear in the size of the *entire* blob, not in that of the record to remove.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks so much, I decided to go your way. one more question, which way is faster when returning a list of all logs to the user?  I mean jsonfield stores the data together, is it easier to find than separate storage?

Comment: @Answer_K: if you use `prefetch_related`, likely both are comparable in terms of performance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related